# How to restart Map Reduce Hadoop job using Spring Batch Yarn Application?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, spring-data, spring-batch, restart

I have Map Reduce application and i want to use Spring Batch Yarn logic.
Like the one mentioned in below link.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/yarn-batch-restart/

But i want it to be really specific as normally we have in hadoop map reduce jobs.
Just looking for Spring Batch Yarn Class and configuration. Considering my hadoop map reduce logic is already inplace and working.

Thanks in  Advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ApplicationContext Configuration that u were looking for

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:hdp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop" xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop/spring-hadoop.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.2.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />
    <hdp:configuration namenode-principal="hdfs://xx.yy.com" rm-manager-uri="xx.yy.com"
        security-method="kerb" user-keytab="location" rm-manager-principal="username"
        user-principal="username">
        fs.default.name=${fs.default.name}
        mapred.job.tracker=${mapred.job.tracker}
    </hdp:configuration>

    <hdp:job id="wordCountJobId" input-path="${input.path}"
        output-path="${output.path}" jar-by-class="com.xx.poc.Application"
        mapper="com.xx.poc.Map" reducer="com.xx.poc.Reduce" />

    <hdp:job-runner id="wordCountJobRunner" job-ref="wordCountJobId"
        run-at-startup="true" />
</beans>
```